# How do you run a java program from a bash script?

Tags: bash, java, scripts

I am trying to run a minecraft server from a "run.sh" script. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

I'm running the script from the same directory as the minecraft_server.jar, and it does nothing. I want it to open a terminal window that is running the java program. I am new to Linux so I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't do anything? As I understand it, you're specifically asking it not to display anything, but only run silently in the background.

Comment: If I am I'm not trying to, what I want it to do is open a terminal window running the server.

Comment: What happens when you run the script from the command line?

Comment: Can you please try the following and report the output `which java` to see if the java paths are being picked. Also it could be running as a daemon so can you please try `ps -ef | grep java` to see if it is running as a background process. Finally, can your please run `cd <directory you are running from>; fuser . ` to see if there are multiple processes started from that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that running the script doesn't show a terminal window, the solution depends on the window manager you're using. Gnome as well as KDE allow to edit properties of desktop shortcuts on a right-click and setting a option like "run in terminal" there.

Another way is to edit the desktop configuration file manually: you can find them in the `Desktop` subdirectory of your home dir. Just add a line with `Terminal=true` to the desktop configuration file that should run the server.

Comment: It works, thank you! When I double click the bash file it opens a window with some options, one is "run in terminal", I could of sworn I tried this earlier and it didn't work but it does now so thats good. Also, is there any way to make it automatically do this? I am using the default gnome in 11.1 btw.

Comment: ah - ok, you didn't create a desktop shortcut yet? I think this is the easiest way. Just right-click on the desktop, select `create starter` or something like that, and enter the path to the bash script. Among the properties of the shortcut, there's something like `run in terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `echo`? That just prints the rest of the line as a sequence of literals to the terminal.

Comment: Changed it. I had it without echo originally, but it doesn't work either, so I was just trying stuff.